# Почему не работает клик по элементу Selemium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Есть ссылка на сайт https://sport-tv-guide.live/settings/countries
после перехода, отметки нужных стран хочу перейти на главную кликом по элементу сверху слева, где изображение. Как только не пытался, получаю разные ошибки. Новичок, прошу помощи.

Comment: 1. На каком ЯП вы пишете) в принципе можно догадываться, и методы не сильно отличаются у разных ЯП, но для ясности было-бы не плохо знать)

2. Покажите что вы попробовали, сложно по белому экрану сказать что же не так в процессе))

Comment: 3. Если вы хотите перейти на главную страницу, и у вас не получается .click(), почему бы не использовать .get() с адресом главной страницы

Comment: Пробовал все правильно и по гайдам. проблема была в том что внизу стр был элемент который визуально не мешал, но требовал нажать ок, без этого клик по другим элементам селениумом  не работал. Принятие соглашения о куках

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробовал все правильно и по гайдам. проблема была в том что внизу стр был элемент который визуально не мешал, но требовал нажать ок, без этого клик по другим элементам селениумом не работал. Принятие соглашения о куках